# globbing a range with padded 0's- python

Tags: python, glob

Quick question regarding globbing in python.

I have a directory of files that go 'sync_0001.tif', 'sync_0002.tif', ... , 'sync_2400.tif'. I'd like to obtain 3 subset lists of those files: 1 for the first 800 files, second 800 files, and last 800 files. The only problem is the 0's before the numbers. I can't figure out the right way to glob and obtain those lists. The third list is easy because there are no 0's padding any of those files (s3=glob.glob('sync_[1601-2400].tif'). The other two are trickier because the number of 0's out front varies.

I tried this, but got 'bad character range,' I'm guessing because of the 0's:

```
s1 = glob.glob('sync_' + '{[0001-0009], [0010-0099], [0100-0800]}' + '.tif')
s2 = glob.glob('sync_' + '{[0801-0999], [1000-1600]}' + '.tif')
```

I then tried moving the 0's out front like so, but got an empty list:

```
s1 = glob.glob('sync_' + '{000[1-9], 00[10-99], 0[100-800]}' + '.tif')
```

What's the best way to achieve these three lists? I'm starting to think I have the whole glob thing wrong, so if someone could shed some light that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The [`fnmatch()` syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) used by `glob` is not nearly sophisticated enough..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) underpinning the `glob.glob()` function is not nearly sophisticated enough for your task.

Just grab *all* filenames and partition them after sorting:

```
filenames = sorted(glob.glob('sync_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].tif'))
```

This works because your numbers are padded and can thus be sorted lexicographically. Then partition them:

```
s1 = [f for f in filenames if 0 < int(f[5:9]) <= 800]
s2 = [f for f in filenames if 800 < int(f[5:9]) <= 1600]
s3 = [f for f in filenames if 1600 < int(f[5:9]) <= 2400]
```

The directory I/O will be the slowest here anyway. You can make this all a little more efficient by looping just once and swapping what you append to:

```
target = s1 = []
s2 = []
s3 = []
for f in filenames:
    num = int(f[5:9])
    if num > 800:
        target = s2
    elif num > 1600:
        target = s3
    target.append(f)
```

but for a task like this sticking to the simpler list comprehensions is just fine too.

Comment: Not all the files are `sync_`, some are `sync999` and others `sync 000`; unless that was a typo in the original question.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: the sample attempts at globbing use the pattern I used in my answer. I assume the exceptions are a typos.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes, sorry. that was a mistake. thank you both for your answers! I'll accept this answer because it is close to my original solution and I can do it in only 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is simply:

1. Glob all the files that start with `sync`
2. Sort the list by the number component
3. Split it into chunks of 800

Since you already know globbing, the rest is:

```
import glob
import re
from itertools import izip_longest

# https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


def sorter(x):
    return int(re.search('(\d+)',x).groups()[0])

files = glob.glob('sync*.tif')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=sorter)
in_batches = list(grouper(sorted_files, 800))
```

---

As the pattern is always `sync_` (after your edit), you can simplify the code above to the following:

```
files = glob.glob('sync_*.tif')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1]))
in_batches = list(grouper(sorted_files, 800))
```

Comment: thank you. This is also a viable solution. I tried voting up but do not have enough reputation. thanks again